# What does this error mean? [GatekeeperXPC]

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avasset

I get this error:

```
[GatekeeperXPC] Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died
```

What does it mean? (I am currently working with AVAssets)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you fix it? Did you find the problem?